# Meilisearch Filter Rails Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meilisearch

I am looking for a better way of filtering an array of values through Maeiliseach using an array. I have users that can have multiple accounts and want to search all of a users accounts inventory. I have indexed the Inventory items.

This what  a current do

```
Inventory.search("",{filter: ['account_id = 4 OR account_id = 5']})
```

I can use

```
accounts = user.accounts.pluck(:id)
```

to get all the id's. Once I have them I can turn it into a string for answer like this 'account_id = 4 OR account_id = 5'. But seems like that might not be the best way and I am missing something. Any help much appreciated. The documentation didn't seem to have the answer I was looking for but maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong version of pagy that is why I was getting the errors.